# log4net do not rename existing spawned log files

Tags: c#, log4net

How can I configure the log4net appender to log into the default log file name, and spawn log files when the current log file reaches its defined limit, but leave the existing spawned log files in tact.

Example (log appender logs to `log.log`)

log.log
log.1.log
log.2.log

log.log reaches its size limit, what I want is that log.log gets renamed to log.3.log, instead of log.1.log (and log.1.log becomes log.2.log, and log.2.log becomes log.3.log).

I thought I could achieve this with the `StaticLogFileName` property, but that does not seem to be the case.

Current appender:

```
<appender name="ContextLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\IAI\Logs\ContextLog\context_log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
    <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <header value="%newline===[SOFTWARE STARTUP AT  %date]===%newline" type="log4net.Util.PatternString" />
      <footer value="%newline===[SOFTWARE SHUTDOWN]===%newline%newline" type="log4net.Util.PatternString" />
      <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff} [%-5level][thread: %thread][%logger] %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
      <levelToMatch value="PRODUCTION" />
    </filter>
  </appender>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the setting, the direction can be configured with `countDirection`.

```
  <appender name="ContextLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\IAI\Logs\ContextLog\context_log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true"/>

    *<countDirection value="1"/>*
```

- `countDirection < 0` will result in log file 1 to be renamed to log file 2.
- `countDirection > 0` will result in log files to keep their file name, and the newest spawned log file having the biggest number.